# Jsoup Asynctask implementing fragments with value from previous activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, jsoup

I've an activity MainActivity.java which sends a string value to another activity ViewFragActivity.java in which I have to implement 4 fragments. In each fragments I have to fetch data using jsoup accordingly with the string that I received from the previous activity. I'm getting a nullpointer exception that's what my problem is..Instead of fragment I used activity the jsoup worked correctly. I think the problem is with implementing asynctask within the fragment. Somebody?

ViewFrag.java

```
public class ViewFragActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener{
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
private String[] tabs = { "Movies", "Games", "Fun", "Events" };
Bundle extras;
public String key;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_frag);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    key = intent.getStringExtra("String");
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {        
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.view, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
```

}

Fragment1.java

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
TextView respText, date;
String url1 = "";
.....
String url7 = "";//Each containing URLs
.....
String url12 = "";

ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_daily, container,
            false);
    init();
    return rootView;
}
private void init() {
    respText = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.site_name_2);
    date = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.date);
    String key = ((ViewFragActivity) this.getActivity()).key;
    switch (key) {
    case "A":
        new Test(getActivity()).execute(url1);
        break;
    case "B":
        new Test(getActivity()).execute(url2);
        break;
    case "C":
        new Test(getActivity()).execute(url3);
        break;
        ......//more cases

    }

}

public class Test extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    String desc;
    String dat;
    Activity mContex;
    public  Test(Activity context)
    {
     this.mContex=context;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),"",null, true);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Astro");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params[0];
        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements myin = document.select("div#monday");
            org.jsoup.nodes.Element firstdate = myin.select("p:eq(0)")
                    .first();
            org.jsoup.nodes.Element secondParagraph = firstdate
                    .nextElementSibling();
            desc = secondParagraph.text();
            dat = firstdate.text();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        respText.setText(desc);
        date.setText(dat);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

LOg

```
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411): Process: com.chiron.astrotest, PID: 23411
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at        com.chiron.astrotest.Fragment1.init(Fragment1.java:58)
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at       com.chiron.astrotest.Fragment1.onCreateView(Fragment1.java:53)
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at  android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:482)
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2553)
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
10-04 12:04:38.847: E/AndroidRuntime(23411):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
```

**UPDATE**:New logcat

```
10-04 12:38:35.994: E/AndroidRuntime(30527): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 12:38:35.994: E/AndroidRuntime(30527): Process: com.chiron.astrotest, PID: 30527
10-04 12:38:35.994: E/AndroidRuntime(30527): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 12:38:35.994: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at com.chiron.astrotest.Fragment1$Test.onPostExecute(Fragment1.java:145)
10-04 12:38:35.994: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at com.chiron.astrotest.Fragment1$Test.onPostExecute(Fragment1.java:1)
10-04 12:38:35.994: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
10-04 12:38:35.994: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
10-04 12:38:35.994: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
10-04 12:38:35.994: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-04 12:38:35.994: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-04 12:38:35.994: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
10-04 12:38:35.994: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 12:38:35.994: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-04 12:38:35.994: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
10-04 12:38:35.994: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
10-04 12:38:35.994: E/AndroidRuntime(30527):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**UPDATE Working Code**

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
TextView respText, date;
String url1 = "";
.....
String url7 = "";//Each containing URLs
.....
String url12 = "";

ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_daily, container,
            false);
   respText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.site_name_2);//CHANGE
   date = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.date);//CHANGE
    init();
    return rootView;
}
private void init() {
    respText = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.site_name_2);
    date = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.date);
    String key = ((ViewFragActivity) this.getActivity()).key;
    switch (key) {
    case "A":
        new Test(getActivity()).execute(url1);
        break;
    case "B":
        new Test(getActivity()).execute(url2);
        break;
    case "C":
        new Test(getActivity()).execute(url3);
        break;
        ......//more cases

    }

}

public class Test extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    String desc;
    String dat;
    Activity mContex;
    public  Test(Activity context)
    {
     this.mContex=context;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),"",null, true);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Astro");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params[0];
        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements myin = document.select("div#monday");
            org.jsoup.nodes.Element firstdate = myin.select("p:eq(0)")
                    .first();
            org.jsoup.nodes.Element secondParagraph = firstdate
                    .nextElementSibling();
            desc = secondParagraph.text().toString();//CHANGE
            dat = firstdate.text().toString();//CHANGE
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        respText.setText(desc);
        date.setText(dat);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: show the line at Fragment1.java:  58 line

Comment: line 57  private void init() {                                   line 58  respText = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.site_name_2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fragment , getview may be null value ,so declare the value in oncreatview ,like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_daily, container,
        false);

   respText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.site_name_2);
   date = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.date);
   init();
   return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Now fragment is opened. But something is wrong with onPostexcecute

Comment: use like this:desc = secondParagraph.text().tostring();
            dat = firstdate.text().tostring();

Comment: print the log at the below the desc and dat,and then show the line Fragment1.java:145

Comment: Log not printed.              line145   respText.setText(desc);
  line146 date.setText(dat);

Comment: i think you got the value is null,so that the null pointer exception,first check the desc String length >0 ,if it's true ,set the text respText.setText(desc);  or else  means ,check your network reponse value.

Comment: Its not null. I toasted the dat in onPostExcecute ,and got the date toasted.

Comment: I think the problem is with setting the text to TextView.

Comment: OOPS...Sorry I put this in onCreateview--- respText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.site_name_2);
    date = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.date);-----and this in init()----respText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.site_name_2);
  date = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.date);----

Comment: removed those two from init()...and worked Thanks a lot.